# AMCL Localization, Drifts when turning

Tags: navigation, mapping, pose, scan, hector-localization

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi people, I am using a differential drive robot with a sick laser scanner.

When I am driving him forwards everything is fine but when I start turning the LaserScan doesnt match with the map and it starts drifting.

I am only using AMCL and not robot_pose_ekf, do I need to use this?

Here is my current tf tree.
[image: image description]

Here is a Screenshot when I drove forwards:
[image: image description]

and once I am starting to turn the robot the laserscan (red boxes) dont match with the map anymore :/
I have really no idea where to look for the mistake:
[image: image description]

Hope you can help, greeting

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/208466/amcl-localization,-drifts-when-turning/) by [felixwatzlawik](https://answers.ros.org/users/22115/felixwatzlawik/) on ROS Answers with karma: 201 on 2015-05-04

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [fxgovers](https://answers.ros.org/users/25989/fxgovers/) on 2016-07-16**:
I'm having much the same problem, if anyone can help.

Francis G.

**Comment by [Dharmateja Kadem](https://answers.ros.org/users/26024/dharmateja-kadem/) on 2016-09-19**:
Hi, did you find the solution for this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can check your vehicle model. For example, wheelbase of the robot may be set incorrectly since you only have problem when rotating.

---

Originally posted by [Akif](https://answers.ros.org/users/23527/akif/) with karma: 3561 on 2016-09-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Dharmateja Kadem](https://answers.ros.org/users/26024/dharmateja-kadem/) on 2016-09-20**:
My robot's wheelbase is at the center of the back wheels, will that be any problem?

**Comment by [Akif](https://answers.ros.org/users/23527/akif/) on 2016-09-21**:
You may check the distance between two wheels in y-axis and x-axis (if any). Also you can share your odometry calculation method (vehicle model).

**Comment by [gleb](https://answers.ros.org/users/27760/gleb/) on 2016-09-26**:
Hi Akif,
I have the same problem. I am using a carlike robot simulated in gazebo.  As odom_model_type I am using "diff". But amcl has no parameter specifying the wheelbase. Do you have any idea how to correct that localization drift?
Tank you.

**Comment by [Henrique](https://answers.ros.org/users/28087/henrique/) on 2016-09-27**:
For car type robots, you need to write a custom odometry algorithm with the math based on ackerman equations. They can be simplified with bike equations.

**Comment by [gleb](https://answers.ros.org/users/27760/gleb/) on 2016-09-28**:
Do you mean a custom amcl-odom-model-type?

**Comment by [Henrique](https://answers.ros.org/users/28087/henrique/) on 2016-09-29**:
No, amcl, infere its new position by odom pose of the robot (the position in the map that the robot think it is), plus laserscan and instant movement (in odom too). So what you need to do is to make your odom publish correct. (make a topic that reads the joint states and pubblish the correct odom)